# QSpatiaLite query syntax

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, spatialite

Using the QSpatiaLite plugin in QGIS I composed the following query

SELECT  'AddressPoint_2'.'buildingNu', 'AddressPoint_2'.'postCode' WHERE  'AddressPoint_2'.'postCode' = 'NR13 3AA'  FROM  'AddressPoint_2'

This returns an error:

"The SQL query seems to be invalid near "FROM":syntax error."

A previous query:

SELECT   'AddressPoint_2'.'buildingNu', 'AddressPoint_2'.'postCode' FROM 'AddressPoint_2'

runs OK. I cannot see why the slightly more complicated query is failing on the same use of FROM

Any pointers please?

Comment: Move your FROM clause before your WHERE clause:
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...

Comment: @kyle: Thank you for that. Changing the order as you suggested is the answer. Would you like to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your FROM clause before your WHERE clause: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...